# Where can I find the source for the latest linux kernel 6.0.5?

Tags: apt, kernel, compiling

I have installed the latest kernel 6.05 (`linux-image-unsigned-6.05-060005-generic`).
When I try to get the source code for this kernel I am not able to.

I run :

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

I get the following error:

```
E: unable to find source package for linux-image-6.0.0-060005-generic
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a mainline kernel which is outside of `apt` stuff and not supported here. You can get the source code from [the upstream kernel website](https://kernel.org/) or from the Ubuntu mainline git at:

```
git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel-test/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/mainline-crack cod/mainline/v6.0.5
```

Comment: is this the repo? git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel-test/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/mainline-crack

Comment: there seems to be something(cod/mainline/v6.0.5) after the repo name.

Comment: I copied and pasted from [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.0.5/).